# Resume Training tf.keras Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard

I encountered some problems when I continued training my model and visualized the progress on tensorboard.

[image: Tensorboard Training Visualization]

My question is how do I resume training from the same step without specifying any epoch manually? If possible, simply by loading the saved model, it somehow could read the `global_step` from the optimizer saved and continue training from there.

I have provided some codes below to reproduce similar errors.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[Tensorboard()])
model.save('./final_model.h5', include_optimizer=True)

del model

model = load_model('./final_model.h5')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[Tensorboard()])
```

You can run the `tensorboard` by using the command:

```
tensorboard --logdir ./logs
```

Comment: Even if you load the model, TensorFlow will treat the metrics from the starting point. Also, this is because epochs start again from 0 and not from where it ended like 8 epochs.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the parameter `initial_epoch` in the function `model.fit()` to the number of the epoch you want your training to start from. Take into account that the model trains until the epoch of index `epochs` is reached (and not a number of iterations given by `epochs`). 
In your example, if you want to train for 10 epochs more, it should be:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, initial_epoch=9, epochs=19, callbacks=[Tensorboard()])
```

It will allow you to visualise your plots on Tensorboard in a correct manner.
More extensive information about these parameters can be found in the [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit).

Comment: I know about this method, but I would prefer a method that does not need me to specify the epoch. I think this should not be the only way to do it.

Comment: I, myself, don't see the problem in specifying the epoch as without specifying it is zero just because it was set by default to zero. When loading the model from checkpoint the training indeed starts from the saved point, but you will anyway have to specify the initial epoch parameter, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Here is sample code in case someone needs it. It implements the idea proposed by Abhinav Anand:

```
mca = ModelCheckpoint(join(dir, 'model_{epoch:03d}.h5'),
                      monitor = 'loss',
                      save_best_only = False)
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir = join(dir, 'logs'),
                 write_graph = True,
                 write_images = True)
files = sorted(glob(join(fold_dir, 'model_???.h5')))
if files:
    model_file = files[-1]
    initial_epoch = int(model_file[-6:-3])
    print('Resuming using saved model %s.' % model_file)
    model = load_model(model_file)
else:
    model = nn.model()
    initial_epoch = 0
model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs = 100,
          initial_epoch = initial_epoch,
          callbacks = [mca, tb])
```

Replace `nn.model()` with your own function for defining the model.

Comment: ``epochs = training_epochs + initial_epoch`` in the fit call ensures that the model is trained for the amount of epochs specified, instead of training only for ``training_epochs - initial_epoch`` times.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. Create checkpoints while training the model and then use those checkpoints to resume training from where you left of.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[Tensorboard()])
model.save('./final_model.h5', include_optimizer=True)

model = load_model('./final_model.h5')

callbacks = list()

tensorboard = Tensorboard()
callbacks.append(tensorboard)

file_path = "model-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"

# now here you can create checkpoints and save according to your need
# here period is the no of epochs after which to save the model every time during training
# another option is save_weights_only, for your case it should be false
checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint(file_path, monitor='loss', verbose=1, period=1, save_weights_only=False)
callbacks.append(checkpoints)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=callbacks)
```

After this just load the checkpoint from where you want to resume training again

```
model = load_model(checkpoint_of_choice)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=callbacks)
```

And you are done.

Let me know if you have more questions about this.

Comment: yes, indeed. It starts from exactly the point where the checkpoints were saved rather than starting from the beginning. I would suggest you to give it a try and let me know if you face any issues. you can verify by looking at the loss after resuming the training.

Comment: @HardianLawi also here you don't need to specify the epochs manually, rather the number of epochs you want to run from there.

Comment: Your code does not work for me. I'm not sure why you are suggesting to use the `ModelCheckpoint` callback. If you look at the source code of the checkpoint, it is basically calling the `save` method from the model which is just the same as the code I have provided in the question

Comment: Im not sure how it could work for you. Did you re-instantiate the callbacks?

Comment: because you cannot call model.save in the middle of the training. And your question clearly states you want to start where you left off and ModeCheckpoint certainly provides that a bit more flexibility. And yes you are right, it does call model.save because that is the only way to save models.

Comment: and this code works perfectly, I can assure you of that. So, if its not working for you, please do show how exactly you are using it inside your code so that I can figure out where it is going wrong

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the codes you have provided to me have the same logic as what I have in the question. The difference is only yours saves the model at the end of every epoch, while mine only saves at the end of the training. But, if I try to load the model that has been saved and continue training from there, the `tensorboard` will still give the same problem as the graph in the question.

Comment: okay, got your point. but before going to the tensorboard, does the training starts from the where you left off or is it just that the tensorboard is not displaying it from that point.

Comment: It will restart the epoch unless I specify the argument `initial_epoch`.

Comment: for validation sake i just ran it on my system, and its working. are you still using the above code or have you made any modifications. If yes, please do update in your question.

Comment: What is the tf version you used?

Comment: I am currently using the latest stable version, which is 1.12.0

Comment: sorry it's 1.13.0